# How do I lookup a particular cell in another worksheet dependent on the value of a cell?

Tags: excel, lookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to read in a table called operations that looks like so

```
"id";"name";
"1";"LASER CUTTING";
"2";"DEBURR";
"3";"MACHINING";
"4";"BENDING";
"5";"PEM";
"6";"WELDING";
"7";"PAINT PREPARATION";
"8";"PAINTING";
"9";"SILKSCREEN PREPARATION";
"10";"SILKSCREEN";
"11";"ASSEMBLY - PACKAGING";
"12";"LASER PREP";
```

I want to have a column in a worksheet that gets the appropriate name based on value of an operation_id column in another worksheet.
How do I lookup a particular cell in another worksheet dependent on the value of a cell?

Example

```
userid, operation_id, operation_name
bob, 3, MACHINING
```

Comment: Question: as far as my own experience goes, don't you need at least one value column (to be aggregated) for pivot tables?  Looking at the data you've posted here, it doesn't look like either column would be suitable for aggregation.

Comment: BTW -- sometimes you can 'aggregate' strings by changing the function to min() or max(), etc., instead of the normal math functions like sum, average, etc.  It's kind of a hack, but as long as you don't have duplicates in your string column, it will work.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to aggregate at all, I basically just want to use it to look up the value that I want.

Comment: It seems like you have no problem with the SQL and your whole question deals with how you access the data once you've loaded it into a sheet.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Lookup is what I was looking for, I'm going to edit my tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the Lookup() function would work better for you.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/lookup.php

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the DGET(database,field,criteria) function, reference [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dget-HP005209059.aspx).

Or you can use this worksheet function:

```
VLOOKUP(cellWithID, Sheet2!A1:B13, 2, FALSE)
```

where cellWithID is the cell with the ID value you want to use.

Comment: I do this type of thing every month at my work. I use Vlookup. It was made to do just this sort of thing.  (I am assuming that you want to know how to do this in Excel, since that's one of your tags)

Answer (score 0):

Basing off this: "What I really want to do is just lookup the name for an operation without having to run a sql query every time or have an ugly huge if statement in every cell."

I guess what confuses me here is why you don't just use a join. You can always join that table as a lookup to whatever your sql statement is;

```
select operations.name, tableA.* from tableA
```

left outer join operations on operations.id = tableA.operationid

If you wanted to, you could functionize this; not recommended. Subqueries are generally speaking bad news. However,

```
create function dbo.LookupOperationName
(
@id int
)
returns varchar(100)
as
declare @returnvalue varchar(100)
select @returnvalue = name from Operations where id = @id

return @returnValue
```

would do the trick. Then you could:

```
 select tablea.*,LookupOperationName(operationid) from tablea
```

Again, remember that your join example is much more performant. You could also create a view that had the join, and use the view in place of the table.... all kinds of things.

Comment: Edited my explanation to explain better what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed your question has excel in there. You're probably looking more for an excel based solution... sorry! I see now.